# EXTJS - custom VTYPE

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

I have created a custom vtype that I want to reuse, the vtype will be used to confirm data in the textfield matches another textfield, i.e. confirm  email address,  etc.

The vtype works perfectly except I need a custom error validation message for each of my textfields, currently I am stuck with the default message in the vtype.

I played around and I am able to pass a field called failedValidationTextField  from my view to the vtype, question is how do I get this to be the default message returned back from the vtype?

//vtype

```
confirmTextFieldValidation: function(val, field) {
console.log(field.failedValidationTextField);   //the data is getting passed into the vtype
if (field.initialTextField) {
   var txtField = field.up('panel').down('#' + field.initialTextField);
   return (val === txtField.getValue());
}else{
   return false;
}
```

},
    'confirmTextFieldValidationText': 'This is the message that is currently getting returned'

```
//view
{
xtype: 'textfield',
itemId: 'textfield#1',
msgTarget: 'side',
vtype: 'confirmTextFieldValidation',
failedValidationTextField: 'This is the message I want passed back when validation fails',
].'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [vtypeText](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-vtypeText)

```
confirmTextFieldValidation: function(val, field) {
console.log(field.failedValidationTextField);   //the data is getting passed into the vtype
if (field.initialTextField) {
   var txtField = field.up('panel').down('#' + field.initialTextField);
   //Validation failed message
   field.vtypeText = field.failedValidationTextField;
   return (val === txtField.getValue());
}else{
   return false;
}
```